# Google+ app showing wrong pictures when sharing through Android

Tags: android, google-plus

I have programmatically added Google+ sharing to my app.  I have a set of photos that I include with my posts and share with the following code:

```
private void shareToGooglePlus() {
  // Launch the Google+ share dialog with attribution to your app.
  PlusShare.Builder share = new PlusShare.Builder(this);

  for (String imageFilename : imageList) {
    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(imageFilename));
    share.addStream(imageUri);
  }

  share.setText("My images");
  share.setType("image/jpeg");

  startActivityForResult(share.getIntent(), 0);
}
```

When this code gets executed, the Google+ app on my phone is started and I get a preview that has the images and text as expected.

However, if I run this more than once and include different images on subsequent runs, the original images show up in the Google+ post preview instead of the new ones.  If I submit the post, the correct images show up in the post--the new ones, not the original ones.

I presume the Google+ app has some kind of caching mechanism.  Is there a way to programmatically clear that cache so that the correct images show up in the Google+ app post preview?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try assigning different random names to your source files (by renaming or copying) on each run

Comment: So I copied the files into new files with names based on the time and I am now getting the correct images each time.  However, even though I am loading 13 images to the PlusShare.Builder, every other time I load it, the G+ app shows 24 photos.  Still, the correct 13 images are shared.  Very odd.