# Google+ share dialog show wrong image

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm trying to share image and title on `Google+` using this `method`:

```
share(com.google.android.apps.plus, img, title);
====================================
private void share(String type, int imgResId, String title) {
        boolean found = false;
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/jpeg");

        // gets the list of intents that can be loaded.
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                .queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
        if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
            for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {

                if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase(
                        Locale.ENGLISH).contains(type)
                        || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase(
                                Locale.ENGLISH).contains(type)) {
                    Log.d("pack", info.toString());
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, title);
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(Helper
                            .saveFile(context, imgResId))); // Optional,
                                                            // just if you
                                                            // wanna share
                                                            // an image.
                    share.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
                return;

            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"));
        }
}
```

when `Google+ share dialog` comes up it shows wrong image(the image I try to share on `Google+` the first time).I try to change the image `resource` id but still the same wrong image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google+ app showing wrong pictures when sharing through Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116793/google-app-showing-wrong-pictures-when-sharing-through-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue when trying to reuse a URI for different files, there appears to be an image cache somewhere that doesn't notice that the image changed.

I "fixed" it by generating a different URI for a new image (in your case, use a unique filename each time).  A better solution would be to invalidate that cache, but I'm not aware of how (or if) that can be done.

Comment: It works for me ... what are they(google) trying to do ... I spend days trying to know what's going on.Thank you, I really appreciate this.